# XML not parse with soap-env having custom tags in PHP

Tags: php, xml, soap, xml-parsing

I am experiencing an error while parsing my XML response in PHP

I have a below XML response, when i call from CURL request

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap-env:Header>
        <eb:MessageHeader xmlns:eb="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader" eb:version="1.0" soap-env:mustUnderstand="1">
            <eb:From>
                <eb:PartyId eb:type="URI">Sabre_API</eb:PartyId>
            </eb:From>
            <eb:To>
                <eb:PartyId eb:type="URI">Agency</eb:PartyId>
            </eb:To>
            <eb:ConversationId>2021.01.DevStudio</eb:ConversationId>
            <eb:Service eb:type="sabreXML">Session</eb:Service>
            <eb:Action>TokenCreateRS</eb:Action>
            <eb:MessageData>
                <eb:MessageId>1913771794839350290</eb:MessageId>
                <eb:Timestamp>2023-02-23T22:04:43</eb:Timestamp>
            </eb:MessageData>
        </eb:MessageHeader>
        <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext">
            <wsse:BinarySecurityToken valueType="String" EncodingType="wsse:Base64Binary">T1RLAQLASo74A7olKG7QnepeFqs19UHX+0Cds9QiDZoYfu677xC3Vkr9a+OcQhutjPL4atVMAADQRtHIXdehGg/0OVuPdia/0cM233jFDvyJJHgJHC3o8gV2ssS63b4Y0lgCG59SiG4tmEcqAXcYAMlnq+wJ4TfsOIDFwYdP+D0peSEFBM/m3EyOUqc4idJ+vO4S7xENCeQ7UX4YVKjVLJs788omPDbSIRNo85KQ5QxRprldV0jucJpAtbNfs1DrMHFqNIPyg0CpVpgXILkFx0azkcAuvmbHMHLqqO13WJEOhsG0KDBhBhRn8CwoCgD9foXL24W6yGu8Ecm0Fzvb/MuAjuYm9s48yg**</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
        </wsse:Security>
    </soap-env:Header>
    <soap-env:Body>
        <sws:TokenCreateRS xmlns:sws="http://webservices.sabre.com" Version="1.0.0">
            <sws:Success/>
        </sws:TokenCreateRS>
    </soap-env:Body> </soap-env:Envelope>
```

To parse the above XML i have initially tried with the **simplexml_load_String** but it gives an empty response.

Then i tried **DOM** method by using following code, here considering **$response->Data** is the above XML.

```
    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    $dom->loadXML($response->Data);
    $dom->formatOutput = true;      
    $XMLContent = $dom->saveXML();
```

It gives me following output again:

```
<!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?-->
<soap-env:envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">   <soap-env:header>
    <eb:messageheader xmlns:eb="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader" eb:version="1.0" soap-env:mustunderstand="1">
      <eb:from>
        <eb:partyid eb:type="URI">Sabre_API</eb:partyid>
      </eb:from>
      <eb:to>
        <eb:partyid eb:type="URI">Agency</eb:partyid>
      </eb:to>
      <eb:conversationid>2021.01.DevStudio</eb:conversationid>
      <eb:service eb:type="sabreXML">Session</eb:service>
      <eb:action>TokenCreateRS</eb:action>
      <eb:messagedata>
        <eb:messageid>1002038859236010450</eb:messageid>
        <eb:timestamp>2023-02-23T23:52:03</eb:timestamp>
      </eb:messagedata>
    </eb:messageheader>
    <wsse:security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext">
      <wsse:binarysecuritytoken valuetype="String" encodingtype="wsse:Base64Binary">T1RLAQJZqih4+TYQmYCcdj42lcej5nckNWdo6WNb8edNl3xNtxAkqmu2YKjKki1OKQ7B3HK3AADQCGiRWrlzFPM0KB4foAOsSF+I+5eXE32uQ23LLd+hOduY2BCJYqPw7CvwCJ/LfNjy3P+QyvClvu6ysctC3a0GjmixDPDqCIckcXPb+XDFyYhR5G5QzQjch/Eax25koLnNvfN8rlvjNq+ENJmaV17wP43GLo1pzd19d9HGMn1VgjrJiVGWAb1ezyeiFNAd1VuBD2lAmdlo4jvZJzAS/fklZvwNFbKME64YpaFRptoLz0FKmz47y1TVYFtV6TZxbKirP3PDms0aGlItbJ4apPSB2Q**</wsse:binarysecuritytoken>
    </wsse:security>   </soap-env:header>   <soap-env:body>
    <sws:tokencreaters xmlns:sws="http://webservices.sabre.com" version="1.0.0">
      <sws:success>
    </sws:success></sws:tokencreaters>   </soap-env:body> </soap-env:envelope>
```

So i plan to get data from **NODE** like below

> $XMLContent->getElementsByTagName('soap-env:header')->item(0)->nodeValue);

**But instead of giving me a node values it start giving me and error.**

I just want to get the data in the node `wsse:binarysecuritytoken`

Did anyone experience some thing like this?

Can you please help me in that??

**UPDATE**
Tried also following, but got not helpful still

```
$domDocument = new DOMDocument();
$domDocument->loadXML($XMLContent);
$carriers=array();
$results=$domDocument->getElementsByTagName("wsse:Security");
foreach($results as $result)
{
    foreach($result->childNodes as $node)
    {
        if($node instanceof DOMElement)
        {
            array_push($carriers, $node->textContent);
        }
    }

}
var_dump($carriers);
```

Comment: I tried even "SimpleXMLElement" as shows here, https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php but not helpful

Comment: Can you edit your question and show your expected output?

Comment: @JackFleeting mate as i already mentioned, it only needs to extract value provided in the tag; "I just want to get the data in the node wsse:binarysecuritytoken "

Comment: There are 3 data items associated with that tag: two attributes and one text value. I'm guessing that in this case you are interested in the text value, but your readers shouldn't have to guess...

Comment: @JackFleeting Yes mate, i managed to get it sorted, please see my below answer, that might be helpful for many

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is SOAP, an object serialization format that uses XML syntax. Best solution is to use a SOAP library. PHP has `ext/soap` for this. Using an XML library would be a level lower.

The XML uses namespaces. Namespaces are specified using unique URIs. For readability/maintainability XML defines aliases for the URIs and uses them as prefixes for node names. However the following 3 examples all should be read as `{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope`:

- `<soap-env:envelope xmlns::soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/Envelope/"/>`
- `<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"/>`
- `<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"/>`

Namespaces can be defined on any element node, so they can change even in a single document. That means that your code should not depend on the aliases/prefixes in the document, but the namespace URIs.

I strongly suggest defining an array variable/constant for the used namespaces. Then you can use Xpath and the namespace aware DOM methods (with the suffix `NS`).

```php
// used namespaces, the keys do NOT need to match the prefixes in the XML.
$xmlns = [
    'soap' => 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/',
    'eb' => 'http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader',
    'sec' => 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext'
];

$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXML(getSoapXmlString());
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);
// register your aliases for the namespaces
foreach ($xmlns as $alias => $uri) {
    $xpath->registerNamespace($alias, $uri);
}

$token = $xpath->evaluate(
  'string(//sec:Security/sec:BinarySecurityToken)'
); 

var_dump($token);
```

`DOMXpath::evaluate()` allows for Xpath expression that return node lists and scalar values. If you cast a node list (specified by a location path) to string it will return the text content of the first node or an empty string.

Comment: thank you @ThW , i tried that but failed, i figured it out mate in another way, please see the below answer.

Comment: It works see: https://3v4l.org/2CLIk#v8.2.3 The solution you posted depends on the prefixes in the XML, which it should not.

Comment: what in case of SOAP-ENV:Body

Comment: i tried your way but it wont work i child node case, https://3v4l.org/C9Hsl

Comment: i mean i am looking for object or array as you can see it is giving string.

Comment: i tried other way aswell, but not working :-( https://3v4l.org/TEmiu

Comment: i tried other way and it works, https://3v4l.org/4ujYB

Comment: In your first try you used the XML string as a dynamic variable name - here is a `$` before `$soapResponse` that should not be there. I you fix this it will return the text content of the soap Body node. But you might want to look at the documentation for Xpath expressions. An expression like `//soap:Body` will return a list of nodes that you can iterate with foreach. Also `DOMXpath:evaluate()` has a second argument that allows you to specify a context node for the expression.

Comment: ok sir, i will check that way aswell and update you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok finally after spent hours, i got that!
I had to modify according to tag names as below, in the most parent i had to used **soap-env** instead of SOAP.

```
            $dom = new DOMDocument;
            $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
            $dom->loadXML($response->Data);
            $dom->formatOutput = true;      
            $XMLContent = $dom->saveXML();

            $xml = simplexml_load_String($XMLContent, null, null, 'soap-env', true);    

            if(!$xml)
                trigger_error("Encoding Error!", E_USER_ERROR);
            
            $Results = $xml->children('soap-env',true);
                
            foreach($Results->children('soap-env',true) as $fault){
                if(strcmp($fault->getName(),'Fault') == 0){
                    trigger_error("Error occurred request/response processing!", E_USER_ERROR);
                }
            }
    
            foreach($Results->children('wsse',true) as $nodes){         
                if(strcmp($nodes->getName(),'Security') == 0){
                    foreach($nodes->children('wsse',true) as $securityNodes){
                        if(strcmp($securityNodes->getName(),'BinarySecurityToken') == 0){                           
                            $tokenParsed = (string)$securityNodes;                                                      
                        }
                    }
                }           
            }
```